# How to declare custom map dataviz in vega?

Tags: d3.js, dictionary, mediawiki, data-visualization, vega

I've develop a dataviz with a map and a [sankey diagram](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/sankey) that I want to embed in a wiki using the *[mediawiki Limn's extension](https://github.com/WikimapsAtlas/mediawiki-extensions-Limn)* (which use [vega](https://github.com/trifacta/vega) library).

[image: ECV-IJBA map/sankey diagram dataviz]

After reading `vega`'s documentation and looking at the [editor map example](https://trifacta.github.io/vega/editor/index.html?spec=map), I'm **wondering if it's even possible to declare this dataviz in `vega`**, Either as one or two *visualizations*?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'll note there is also a "Graph" extension now which uses Vega too and was enabled on all Wikimedia projects.